# Wikipedia - CMS

Tags: user-registration

I am working on Wordpress - Blogging Application.

Like Wikipedia or Livejournal .. How to allow a registered users in my Web-Blog site to write their blogs or contents ?

If i need to write any blogs on my site, its simple normal process. But making the blogging site .. little bit of commercial by allowing the users to register and to blog on my site .. is our goal ..!

Comment: Your description is way too generic. What do you intend to do? Do you want to allow your users simply to create posts that are then posted on your blog? Please edit your question.

Comment: i.e allowing users to register on my blogging site and there by increasing the blogging content. For example, if i am having a blogging site about SQL Database .. i need any users who register on my site can write new blog contents about SQL

Comment: Close-voted as **not a real question**: *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Answer (score 1):

Try **BuddyPress**. It's the best for what you need.

Or try to open the blog for registration and make the new users Subscribers or Contributors.